# php two layer array key search

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

```
$arr = array (

    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'john'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'elisabeth'
    )
);
```

Let's say all we know is the 'id' of the inner array, what would be the best way to search for $arr element, that contains an array, that contains our id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function search($id)
{
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (isset($item['id']) && $item['id'] == $id) {
            return $item; // or whatever you want to return
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
function search($id)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
        if (isset($item['id']) && $item['id'] == $id) {
            return $key; // Return key...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and `return false;` if not found

Comment: yea, but i need the key, of that element, for instance id=4 returns 1 and id=1 returns 0

Comment: i'm new to php, so i'm afraid of "doing it wrong"

Comment: added updated code to return key

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array (

0 => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'john'
),
1 => array(
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'elisabeth'
)
);
foreach($arr as $a)
if($a["id"] == 4)
echo $a["name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_filter

```
$arr = array (

    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'john'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'elisabeth'
    )
);

$id = 1;
$result = array_filter($arr, function($el) use ($id) {
    return $el['id'] == $id;
});
echo '<pre>', var_dump($result), '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'john'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'elisabeth'
    )
);

$search = 4;
$result = null;

array_walk(
    $array,
    function ($element) use ($search, &$result) {
        if (isset($element['id']) && (int)$element['id'] === (int)$search) {
            $result = $element;
        }
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```